# How can a Value for a Start/End JavaScript Function be Equal to an Index that it Should be Between?

Tags: javascript, substring

Per reference to the following link, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

If "start" is greater than "end", it will swap the two arguments:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(4, 1);
```

The result of res will be:

ell

I'm kind of a bit confused with this descriptional excercise, because it is stated that a substring extracts characters from a string **BETWEEN** two indices not including the "end" itself. So if the indices are 4 and 1 representing "o" and "e", why isn't the new string equal to "ll" since these values are **BETWEEN** 1 and 4 and not including the "end". How can the result be "ell" when "e is **NOT** between 1 and 4 but **IS** the value of 1? Please help me where my understanding faileth!

Comment: I think you understand how substring works. You are really asking why is the documentation so confusing, or?

Comment: @ControlAltDel, exactly! Thankyou! The description in [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), should be that "a substring method extracts characters in a string between the index that precedes "start" and the index following the "end" value". To not word it like this is absolutely stupid! Don't you think?

Comment: Is it stupid not to word it like this? Maybe. This is the sort of thing where I think examples can often be more useful than a description. It's tricky because what you'd really rather specify are the indexes of the null space *between* characters, not the character indexes themselves, you know what I mean? And there isn't a convention for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array starts at 0. A string is an array of characters. So H = 0. e = 1, l = 2, l = 3, o = 4. 
The substring doesn't include the end but it does include the start.
So between 1 and 4 you get "ell" = 1(start)23.

Comment: So therefore, the description in [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), should be that '"a substring method extracts characters in a string between the index that precedes "start" and the index following the "end" value'

Comment: That's if you use the swapped version. I definitely do not advise to use it that way. The best way would be to use the correct way around and use substring(1,4) instead of substring(4,1) since substring(4,1) will simply be interpreted has substring(1,4).

Comment: Correct description could be : "The substring method extracts characters in a string between the index of "start" and the index preceding the "end" value"

Comment: Too bad W3Schools pages can't be edited like Wikipedia....JavaScript is already hard enough to learn, why aren't people who are knowledgeable about it able to explain it properly!? It took me some time just to make sense out of the information presented at that link....pissed! Thanks for the help man!

Comment: It can definitely be confusing sometimes. No problem, glad I could help.